# How to work with find?

Tags: matlab, find

I have a problem with find. I don't know what is the problem.

I want to find indices in a matrix by respect to another matrix that have same X , Y and different Z.

My matrix are `selectedl` and `selectedf` with similar rows and different rows so.

```
exP=find(selectedl(:,[1,2])==selectedf(:,[1,2]) & selectedl(:,3)~=selectedf(:,3));
```

what is the issue in the line?

Comment: What error do you get? What are the matrix sizes?

Comment: Assuming matrix `A = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9;10 11 12]` and matrix `B = [4 5 6;7 8 -1; 10 11 12; 10 11 -1; 4 5 6]` What would you like to show?

Comment: I want to find the rows that have same X and Y and different Z.

For example I want [7 8 9;10 11 12] from first matrix OR [7 8 -1;10 11 -1] from second matrix.
Thanks.

Comment: @ahmadhosseini my answer will give you `[7 8 9;10 11 12]` from that example...?

Answer (score 1):

A more readable version would be:

```
A = selectedl == selectedf;
exP = find(A(:,1) & A(:,2) & ~A(:,3));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly (first column is *x*, second is *y*, third is *z*, each row represents a different point), you just need to add row-wise `all` in the first part:

```
exP=find(all(selectedl(:,[1,2])==selectedf(:,[1,2]),2) & selectedl(:,3)~=selectedf(:,3));
```

Or, perhaps more readable:

```
exP=find(selectedl(:,1)==selectedf(:,1) & selectedl(:,2)==selectedf(:,2) & selectedl(:,3)~=selectedf(:,3));
```

This assumes both matrices have the same size and order matters. If not, see @Dan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be using `ismember` instead of `find`:

```
[incl, indices] = ismember(selectedl(:,1:2), selectedf(:,1:2), 'rows');  %// Or possibly ismember(selectedf(:,1:2), selectedl(:,1:2), 'rows') depending on what you're after
excl = ismember(selectedl, selectedf, 'rows');
indices(incl & ~excl)
```

This way your rows don't have to correspond 1 to 1 across the two matrices and teh matrices don't even need to be of the same length.